# Speeding up a query joining two gigantic tables

Tags: mysql, sql

We have to speed up the response of a MySQL database query which joins against two truly gigantic tables (both have >100 million rows.)   There are two problems:   One, the query is slow.   Two, the resultset size can be from zero rows up to thousands of rows.    Ideally we'd like to both speed up the query and limit the size of the resultset to some (adjustable) maximum.

Anybody have a favorite way of segmenting tables or something, where we could accomplish this?

Just looking for ideas here.

Comment: What's the query?  What indices are in place?

Comment: Regarding limiting the result set, you may be able to do that by the way the where clause gets generated.  If this query is initiated by a web page, you have opportunities to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use `explain` to see if indexes are used. Even with 100 million rows, a well indexed table should perform very good. It takes a bit to understand what `explain` is telling you but it's worth it.

If after doing that you still need to segment, I'd recommend looking into [mysql partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html). Make sure you use `explain partitions` and that the queries are only looking into a small number of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the result set size by using `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
LIMIT 50;
```

Will show records 1-50

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
LIMIT 50, 50;
```

Will show records 51-100

As for speeding up the query we'll need more information.  If you want to page the results you'll want to run the lengthy query once and put the results in a table, then page the results from there.